# Mysql join query for showing friends posts with viewstatus!=public

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table **tbl_user, tbl_posts, tbl_friends**

**tbl_user** stores all the user datas.

**tbl_friends** stores which user are friends with other.

**`tbl_posts`**, where the users posts are stored. **`userid`** is the field where all the users id are stored. **`p_viewstatus`** field stores the **view status** of the posts. if the **view status** of the **my friends posts** is **only by me** then that posts should not shown to other users

If sam have a post with id=40 in **`tbl_posts`**. The **`p_viewstatus`** of the post is **only by me** then that post must only be visible to sam only.

If sam have another post with id=41 and **`p_viewstatus`!='only by me'** this post must **visible to all users who are sam's friend**

Tried the following query but don't know how to relate the **p_viewstatus**

**Note: I want to fetch all of my posts and my friends posts from **`tbl_posts`** except the `p_viewstatus` of my friends posts no equal to 'only by me'**

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_posts` as p,`tbl_friends` as f WHERE p.`userid`=f.`userid` and p.`userid`=23
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**BELOW SCREENSHOT SHOWS THE TABLE CONTENTS AFTER JOIN QUERY.**
[image]

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle with some sample data ?

Comment: Sample data will be really helpful!

Comment: @Antoan Milkov Added Database screenshot showing results while executing join query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how your query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_posts` as p 
WHERE p.`userid`=23  OR (p.`userid` IN (SELECT `friendsid` `FROM tblfriends` WHERE `userid`=23)
AND p.`p_viewstatus`<>'only by me')
```

First you select the data from the table you need. After that you filter it with the user id and the ids of the friends of the user and you also tell it that you only want the posts that are not viewable only by me.

Comment: it also hides my post too where its p_viewstatus='only by me'.**I want to hide only myfriends posts where p_viewstatus='only by me'**

Comment: is the IN clause a performance issue? what if user has 50k friends?

Comment: If you have a case where a user can have 50k friends then I'd strongly suggest to use a NoSQL DB for caching the friends ids. I think that twitter were using something like this to generate the home pages of users.